# Undefined variable: ip_address (View:

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an undeclared variable error but cannot see why

I am trying to implement full text search and have the following code

in my controller

```
<?php 

class PostsController extends BaseController {

public function postSearch(){
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

         return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));
         $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 

         array($q))->get();

         return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address'));
}

}
 ?>
```

in my view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
<style>
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700);

    body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        color: #999;
    }

    .welcome {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="search">
{{ Form::model(null, array('route' => array('search'))) }}
{{ Form::text('query', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
{{ Form::submit('Search') }}


@foreach($posts as $post)
<li>{{ $post->instance_id }}</li>
<li>{{ $post->instance_type }}</li>
<li>{{ $post->availability_zone }}</li>
<li>{{ $post->status_checks }}</li>
<li> {{ $post->alarm_status }}</li>
<li> {{ $post->public_dns }}</li>
<li>{{ $post->key_name }}</li>


 @endforeach





@foreach($ip_address as $pip)
<li>{{ $pip->ip_address }}</li>


 @endforeach


{{ Form::close() }}
```

I just cannot for the life of me see the typo

Comment: can you put `print_r($ip_address);` in your view and tell us if it displays anything.

Comment: Hi @Darren tried that but unfortunately getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 return statements.

```
 return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));
 $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 

 array($q))->get();
 return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address'));
```

Try this:

```
public function postSearch(){
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

   $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",         array($q))->get();

   return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address', 'posts'));



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `postSearch` method

```
public function postSearch()
{
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

   return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));

   $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 

   array($q))->get();

   return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address'));
}
```

You have **two** return statments

```
return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));
///...
return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address'));
```

The code after the first returns statement never runs, and an `$ip_address` variable is never sent to the view.  Something like

```
public function postSearch()
{
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

   //return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));

   $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 

   array($q))->get();

   //return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address'));
   return View::make('ec2_instance', [
       'ip_address'=>$ip_address,
       'posts'=>$post
   ]);
}
```

is probably what you want.